# Mouse slightly offset by 3 pixels up and 1 pixel left (pointer image)

Tags: mouse

I noticed that the mouse was slightly offset when trying to click gui components. I decided to test it and it turns out that the pointer is actually offset by 3 pixels up and 1 pixel left. I tested this by writing a small java swing application that just showed x and y positions of various different mouse events. It's not the mouse, I've tried other mice. Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does this always happen to all windows? I recently noticed the same issue when I maximize Firefox and un-maximize it. My workaround is minimizing via plank and open it again.

Comment: yes happens with all windows. I first noticed it when attempting to click the close button on Files.